# Calling associated models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My association is

restaurant.rb (model)

```
has_many :products
```

and in products.rb (model)

```
belongs_to :restaurant
```

Now in my products controller i am basically trying to generate a list of all products and search them with some validation.
I want to show only those products which belong to a specific restaurant

```
def index
                
                case params[:status]
                when 'Active'
                    active_products
                when 'Inactive'
                    inactive_products    
                when 'Sold out'
                    sold_out
                else
                    @products = Restaurant.Product.all #problem arises here
                end

                if params[:search]
                    search
                end

                if params[:section]
                    section
                end

                if params[:sort_by]
                    product_sort
                end
                
            end
```

In the 'else' block of case i want products according to restaurant id. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Product.where(restaurant_id: some_id).all
```

Comment: Thank you. And sorry i can't upvote it because my reputation is less than 15 :(

Comment: No worries! happy hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like

```rb
Restaurant.find(restaurant_id).products
```

Comment: that's two queries, though. If they aren't interested in the restaurant itself, it's a bit wasteful.